# make button in form read php code

Tags: php, jquery, html, button

I'm trying to make the button **on click** read the first php code (so that he can check the username and password if they are correct to move to mainPage), but it doesn't work

here is my `login.php` code

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['Loginbtn'])){
        $una=$_POST['userName'];
        $pass=$_POST['password1'];
        if($una=='Admin'&&$pass=='Admin'){
            $_SESSION['user']=$una;
            header('Location: MainPage.php');
        } else {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
        }
    }
?>
```

and this is my `signIn.php` page code :

```
<?php
    include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
        header("location: home.php");
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <div>
        <div id="rectangle"></div>
            <form id="Form01" name="myForm2" action="" method="post">
                <p id="usern01"> user name</p> <input type="text" name="userName" id="username" > <label id=usernameError></label>
                <p id="password01">password  </p><input type="password" name="password1" id="password"> <label id=passError></label>
                <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button type="button"  id="Loginbtn">    logIn    </button>
            </form>
        <div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my `Mainpage.php` code (if it's help )

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if((!$_SESSION['user'])){
        header("Location: signIn.php?problem=notLoggedIn");
    }

    if(isset($_POST['logoutt'])){
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: signIn.php?problem=goodbye');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is it an ajax request? If not then form action is empty. <form id="Form01" name="myForm2" action="" method="post"> Add the requesting page in the  action attribute of the form.

Comment: have you checked your button works .button type must be submit <button type="submit" name="Loginbtn">Submit</button>.and set action too

Comment: <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> use this in your action

Comment: @RamKesavan i've to tried to change it to sumbit it refreshes the page only , also tried to add the code didn't affect

Comment: <form id="Form01" name="myForm2" action="
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<p id="usern01"> user name</p> <input type="text" name="userName" id="username" > <label id=usernameError></label>
<p id="password01">password  </p><input type="password" name="password1" id="password"> <label id=passError></label> <br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button type="submit"  name="Loginbtn" id="Loginbtn">    logIn    </button>
</form></body></html>

Comment: and  space between and condition  if($una=='Admin'&&$pass=='Admin'){ its works fine in my local

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['Loginbtn'])){
    $una=$_POST['userName'];
    $pass=$_POST['password1'];
    if($una=='Admin' && $pass=='Admin'){
        $_SESSION['user']=$una;
        header('Location: Mainpage.php');
    }
    else {
        $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }

}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    header("location: home.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body >
  <div >
 <div id="rectangle"></div>
  <form id="Form01" name="myForm2" action="
  <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
 <p id="usern01"> user name</p> <input type="text" name="userName" 
 id="username" > <label id=usernameError></label>
  <p id="password01">password  </p><input type="password" 
 name="password1" id="password"> <label id=passError></label> <br>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button type="submit"  name="Loginbtn" id="Loginbtn">    logIn    
  </button>
  </form></body></html>
```

this code redirect to mainpage.php after login with your user name and password. hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You aren't setting the user in the `SESSION` array, set it like this  `$_SESSION['login_user']=$una;` You are looking for user_login index in the SESSION array

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    header("location: home.php");
}
```

which returns false because you haven't set it.

**2.** Your form doesn't submit because the type of your button is not set to submit. Change the button code to `<input type="submit" name="Loginbtn" value="Login">`

OR to

`<button type="submit"  id="Loginbtn" name="Loginbtn">Login</button>` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this updated code to 'signIn.php' file

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script
if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
    header("location: home.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div id="rectangle"></div>
            <form id="Form01" name="myForm2" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                <p id="usern01"> user name</p> <input type="text" name="userName" id="username" > <label id=usernameError></label>
                <p id="password01">password  </p><input type="password" name="password1" id="password"> <label id=passError></label> <br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button type="submit"  id="Loginbtn">    logIn    </button>
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```